# Coil Spring Load and Ride Quality

Tags: chevrolet, suspension, truck

Is there a difference in coil spring load between different engine options for the same model truck?

For example, I have a 1993 C1500 with a 5.7L. Can I use coil springs from another 1993 C1500 but with a 4.3L or a 5.0L engine?

I know they will fit, but will ride quality change?
In other words, are the springs for 5.7 stiffer than the 4.3 or 5.0L?

Comment: I was curious and looked at the O'Reilly auto parts website and they show two or three sets of the same springs regardless of the engine size with a Spring Rate of 870, 1025 and 1090 Lbs/in.  So there's obviously a choice...  Wonder if a Chevy dealer can tell you what the OEM spring rate is?

Comment: Hmm that's interesting. I looked at an online parts catalog but they did not show different spring load ratings.

Comment: Here is [the link](http://www.oreillyauto.com/site/c/search/Coil+Spring/03360/C0361.oap?year=1993&make=Chevrolet&model=C1500%2BPickup%2BRWD&vi=1031331) to the products I found.  I'm not claiming O'Reilly has the best, most accurate catalog - just something I found while looking around.  But, after the physical size of the spring, the spring rate is probably the most important rating for getting the "right" spring.

Comment: @JPhi1618  Do you think your comment is the answer to the question.  It seems that way.  If you agree can you populate an answer and post in chat so it can get it's upvote so it's answered?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When sizing springs for a particular application, manufacturers have to get the right physical size for the job, but they also need to worry about the "spring rate" to properly support a given load.  The spring rate is basically how much weight it takes to compress the spring.

A larger engine is going to be a bigger static load for the suspension, and a quick check of a [parts store website](http://www.oreillyauto.com/site/c/search/Coil+Spring/03360/C0361.oap?year=1993&make=Chevrolet&model=C1500%2BPickup%2BRWD&vi=1031331) shows a few different choices for your model of truck.  Looking at the details on the parts, you will see different spring rates of 870, 1025 and 1090 Lbs/in..  The "heavier duty" springs would be for a larger, heavier engine.

Comment: I think you got a silver badge for this as well.